# C: Read a specific line in the file and return the number

Tags: c, fgets, fread

I have a file "input.dat". In this file, there are 3 lines:

```
1 2 3
5 7 10 12
8 9 14 13 15 17
```

I am going to read one of the three lines using C, and return the number of the elements.
For example, I want to read the 2nd line `5 7 10 12` into memory, and also return the number of values in the 2nd line, which is `4`. My code is below...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STRING_SIZE 2000
int main()
{

        FILE *fp = fopen("in.dat","r");
        char line[STRING_SIZE];
        int lcount=0, nline=1, sum=0, number;

        if (fp != NULL){
                while ( fgets(line, STRING_SIZE, fp) != NULL )
                {
                        if ( lcount == nline ){
                                while (sscanf(line, "%d ", &number)){
                                        sum++;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        else{
                                lcount++;
                        }
                }
                fclose(fp);
        }

        exit(0);
}
```

When I run this code, it never stops like a dead loop. What is the problem here?

Comment: Call `fgets()` N times.

Comment: You can then use `sscanf()` or `strtok()` in a loop to extract the numbers from the line.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you are stuck on writing any code, start by describing **in words** the steps you need to solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is in this loop: `while (sscanf(line, "%d ", &number)){`  because you are scanning the same item again and again. Unlike reading from stdin or so, the scanned item is not "consumed" by sscanf, so you are stuck in an endless loop.